# MySQL Create table, If exist overwrite new values [No use DROP TABLE]

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a table with a query.

Example (with a basic query below):

```
CREATE TABLE teste AS 
SELECT "John" as 'Name', "Dohn" as 'Surname', 18 as 'Age'
```

Alright, we created the table as teste.

Now I will run this query in ever 1 hour;

```
CREATE TABLE teste AS 
SELECT "Selim" as 'Name', "Kenny" as 'Surname', 20 as 'Age'
```

But It says 'Table already exist" of course.
I want to update this table with overwritten new rows.

I can't use 
If the table exists DROP TABLE 
Because, before my query run table goes drop and **if someone wants to show this table It will produce an error**.

I don't wanna keep old rows data, I want to overwrite new rows data as new rows.
When new query result is ready after that delete old rows and add new rows.

Looking for your answers. 
Have a nice day!

Edit:
Simple example:

This table has Top 10 selling products, there's a query working every 1 hour. It's got top 10 selling products with a lot of Joins, Subqueries etc when the query result is ready then overwrite new Top 10 selling products to old Top 10 selling products. I mean this top 10 selling product table can be never empty. (Like truncate first)

Comment: I don't really get the point of this table it doesn't seem as though anybody querying the table has any chance of knowing if the data they get back is current or accurate.

Comment: @P.Salmon Example; This table have Top 10 selling products, there's a query working every 1 hour. It's got top 10 selling products with a lot of Joins, Subqueries etc, when the query result is ready then overwrite new Top 10 selling products to old Top 10 selling products.. Got it? :D

Comment: Have you considered a view?

Comment: @P.Salmon Joins and Subqueries cannot be used in Views.

Comment: have you considered a lock from viewing until truncated and reentered?

Comment: @Siberhecy Joins and Subqueries cannot be used in Views - that's incorrect. - what makes you think otherwise I wonder, there are some restrictions on views https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html

Comment: I look from here; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html Also I tried to create the view with subqueries and joins before and yes there's error View cannot have subqueries, joins.

Comment: Here's a fiddle which disproves what you think. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ed9a2/2

Comment: @Siberhecy can you share the application code where these queries are running. We can use explicit locks on the table to do this. Use `lock tables`; then `truncate table`; then `insert into table`; and eventually `unlock tables`

Answer (score 0):

instead of using drop table you can use Truncate table Query.
   which will simply truncate the table and then you can add your new row.

Comment: Every time you are ready with your new query You just need to do is..   `TRUNCATE TABLE <table_name>` run this Query......It will Make your table empty .... then you can add your new row using Insert Query.